# Java bean server not running properly

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

I am currently using java beans to create an application with a remote interface, i have very simple methods like printDetail which returns "abcd", just a test method. I have a session bean like this:

```
@Stateless
public class MySession implements MySessionRemote {

@Override
public void businessMethod() {
    System.out.println("aaaababa");
}
```

when i deploy the server, i get this error:

> SEVERE: CORE10012: Application previously deployed is not at its
>   original location any more

I use Glassfish 3.1

Comment: Are you talking about GlassFish? Which version?

Comment: @ Moritz Petersen  yes its glassfish 3.1

Comment: It could be a known issue. Try either the latest 3.1.2-5 patch or version 4.

Answer (score 2):

I Found the solution, go to your browser type localhost:4848, select applications in left list, disable any other running apps that was deployed. e.g mine was saying something like

```
SEVERE: CORE10012: Application previously deployed is not at its original location any     more "C:user/ .... / XYZ "
```

Then you should disable the app XYZ because apparently the server is still running this app even if you have created a new one.

Comment: To add to this, I had to go to `localhost:8080`, then click on `Applications` and disable my app.